# How to create web elements array ( selenium)

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I have this web elements:

```
WebElement wikipedia1 = driver.findElement(By.tagName("h1"));
    WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.className("pure-button"));
    WebElement EN = driver.findElement(By.className("js-enabled"));
    WebElement searchfeild1 = driver.findElement(By.className("search-input"));
    WebElement searchfeild2 = driver.findElement(By.id("search-input"));
    WebElement letter = driver.findElement(By.className("sprite-icons-translate-icon"));
```

How can i put them in a web element array?

Comment: What's wrong with `List`?

Comment: The declaration of List would depend on the actions you would perform with the List. Can you update your business requirement? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is basic java stuff

```
WebElement[] elems = {wikipedia1, searchButton, letter};
```

or

```
WebElement[] elems = new WebElement[] {wikipedia1, searchButton, letter};
```